# Derivative of $L_2$ Norm function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

I have an equation of the form $f(x) = ||x - x_0 ||^2$ where $x$ and $x_0$ is in $R^n$.

What I want to do is Taylor expand this about a point - lets call this $x_a$. I know that:
$f(x)$ is approximated $f(x_a) + (\operatorname{grad}(f(x_a))*(x-x_a)$ which is equivalent to $||x_a - x_0 ||^2 + (\operatorname{grad}(f(x_a))*(x-x_a)$.

The problem I have, is that I'm very unsure of how to calculate what $\operatorname{grad}(f(x))$ is.

I'd appreciate any help. (If someone can fix all the notation up, I'd appreciate it too!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For typing convenience, drop the subscripted $x$ variables in favor of
$$a=x_a,\qquad z=x_0$$
Expand the norm using the dot product and write the function as
$$\eqalign{
f &= (x-z)\cdot(x-z) \\
}$$
and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2(x-z)\cdot dx \\
g(x) \;=\; \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2(x-z) \\
}$$
Therefore at $x=a,\,$ the gradient is $\,g(a)=2(a-z)\,$ and the first-order Taylor expansion becomes
$$\eqalign{
f(a+h)
 &\approx f(a) + g(a)\cdot h \\
 &= f(a) + 2(a-z)\cdot h \\
}$$
where $0<\|h\|\ll 1\;$ (i.e. $\,h$ is very small).